# Print font name using LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

I want to print font names (full name, ps name, file name, etc) using LuaTeX's font table. It works fine previously, but recently I encountered an error message from luaotfload

Here is a minimal working example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
\directlua{
  local str = font.fonts[font.current()].fullname
  tex.sprint(-2, str)
}
\end{document}
```

This example, when compiled with LuaTeX works fine. The output PDF has the string `LMRoman10-Regular`, which is the default font. However, if I do not comment out the `setmainfont` line, that is, I load the Minion Pro font, then I got the following error message,

```
error: ...3/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-merged.lua:7656: attempt to perform arithmetic on local 'factor' (a nil value)
.
\newpage ...k \@nobreakfalse \everypar {}\fi \par 
                                                  \vfil \penalty -\@M
```

The relevant line in `luaotfload-merged.lua` and around is,

```
function injections.setkern(current,factor,rlmode,x,tfmchr)
  local dx=factor*x
  if dx~=0 then
    local bound=#kerns+1
    setattr(current,a_kernpair,bound)
    kerns[bound]={ rlmode,dx }
    return dx,bound
  else
    return 0,0
  end
end
```

When I replace the `tex.sprint` line with `inspect`, the console displays correctly `Minion Pro Regular`.

Does anyone has any idea what is going on here?

I am using an up-to-date TeXLive 2013 installation.

Comment: http://tug.org/pipermail/lualatex-dev/2013-June/001571.html

Comment: @phg Thanks for the pointer. It works properly now. If you want, you can put a short answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Indexing the `font.fonts` table can cause the data structures that have been layed out by the font loader to be overwritten. Safe access to those fonts is provided by `font.getfont()`. If you want to retrieve other fonts like e.g. TFM/OFM or virtual fonts, then you will have to write a wrapper like so:

```
local fontdata = fonts.hashes.identifiers
local my_getfont = function (id)
  local f = fontdata[id]
  if f then
    return f
  end
  return font.fonts[id]
end
```

Where `fonts.hashes.identifiers` is where the fontloader keeps the font it initializes.